# Display post to only user friends

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

When user login i want user to only see the post of friends with, I have a separate model for friends and a separate for post how do i filter post by users friends ?

Here is my view

```
def post_list(request):
    
    for user in Post.objects.all():
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            friend_list = FriendList.objects.get(user=request.user )
            friends = friend_list.friends.all()
            context['friends'] = friends
 
  
    context['posts'] = Post.objects.prefetch_related('comments').filter(username=friends).order_by('-date_posted')
  
    return render(request,'feed/feed.html',context)
```

Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="videos",blank=True,null=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    views = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="view")
    shared_body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    shared_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')
    shared_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def post_list(request):
    
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        friend_list = FriendList.objects.get(user=request.user )
        friends = friend_list.friends.all()
        context['friends'] = friends
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(username__in=friends).order_by('-date_posted')
    return render(request,'feed/feed.html',context)
```

**UPDATE**
show current user posts and current user's friends posts.

```
def post_list(request):
    
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        friend_list = FriendList.objects.get(user=request.user )
        friends = friend_list.friends.all()
        context['friends'] = friends
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(username__in=list(friends) + [request.user,]).order_by('-date_posted')
    return render(request,'feed/feed.html',context)
```

Comment: Your solution worked but why when a user share a post by another user who is not my friend i see that person name instead in the shared post  ?

Comment: Amadous Sow Why  don't i see my own post ?

Comment: @Godda because your question is how to `display post to only user friends` ?

Comment: Thank you very much @Thierno Amadou Sow ! Everything is now working perfectly !